# Undefined reference to Scalar::Scalar()

Tags: c++, class, oop

I want to call function from class but it show me error.
my test.cxx file is

```
#include<iostream>
#include"Scalar.hxx"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    Scalar Text;
    char a;
    a=Text.SetBank(1);
    cout<<("%x",a);
    return 0;
    }
```

it show me error

```
undefined reference to `Scalar::Scalar()'
undefined reference to `Scalar::SetBank(char)'
```

Scalar.hxx

```
#ifndef __SCALAR_HXX__
#define __SCALAR_HXX__
#include <stdint.h>
class Scalar
{
    public:
        Scalar(void);
        char SetBank(char bank_no);
};
#endif
```

i have included correct file name.

Comment: Some questions: Are the files in the same folder? Do you get any warnings?  Show full compiler output if you have not. What is your compilation line?

Comment: You have to compile the source file that defines the `Scalar` class (`Scalar.cxx`?) and link that object file with your program.  Including the header allows your code to compile to object file — it doesn't ensure that the object code for the class is available when your program is linked.

Comment: Can you show us the commands you are using for this? Both for compiler and linker, and any make file if there is one?

Comment: no i just run it using g++ text.cxx command,i also don't have any warnings.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think this is a compiler error in itself. Compiler is finding the definition just fine, but your linker cannot find the object files which contain the compiled code for `Scalar` and hence complains.

I have also commented requesting more data to help you with resolving this.

Comment: i also think the same. how can i solve this error

Comment: You mentioned you ran this command `g++ text.cxx`. Assuming `Scalar`'s implementation is in a file named Scalar.cxx, can you try the modification `g++ text.cxx Scalar.cxx`?

Comment: ok i will try both file to compile at one time,or should i create makefile for it.

Comment: For figuring out what the issue is, go without creating a make file for now and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Scalar.hxx provides *declaration* for `Scalar` and `SetBank` methods but I see no *definition*. Is there `Scalar.cxx` file containing the code like the following?

```cpp
Scalar::Scalar() {
    // ctor's body
}

char Scalar::SetBank(char bank_no) {
    // method's body
}
```

If there is then does it get compiled (i.e., included in your project/makefile)?

Comment: yes i have scalar.cxx file

Comment: Then run `g++ scalar.cxx test.cxx`